# Wrong output on strftime() and mktime()

Tags: php, strftime, mktime

Thas my little function:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'de_DE');
$date_array = array($blog_month,$blog_year);
var_dump($date_array); 
$title_date = strftime("%B %Y", mktime(0,0,0, $date_array[0], 0, $date_array[1]));
echo $title_date;
```

the var_dump gives

```
array(2) {
  [0]=> int(5)
  [1]=> int(2013)
}
```

So the array is correct.
But the `$title_date` is always wrong. In this particular case the echo shows `April 2013`.
I guess something is wrong with the `mktime`, because i checked the `timestamp` it gives and it is always the wrong one.

I did read the PHP documentation, and this should be work, don't know whats wrong.
Any idea or suggestion?

best regards
denym

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setlocale` function returns `false` if the locale couldn't be set, and you are ignoring the return value. In this case the call must be failing (possibly because the `de_DE` locale isn't installed?) and `strftime` still formats dates in English.

On the other hand, the day 0 corresponds to the "[last day of the month before](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)". So `mktime` is returning April 30, not May 1 if that's what you expect. For May 1 use this:

```
mktime(0,0,0, $date_array[0], 1, $date_array[1])
```

Comment: Thanks changing the day = 0 to day = 1 was the solution.